# Expression Engine Members Fields - Show All Field Types

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

Hi I am trying to add an upload field and a radio button field for our members in EE2 but when adding a custom member field you only have a choice of text input, text area, or drop down http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/members/custom_member_fields_edit.html#field-type

Is there anyway to have access to all of the field types in EE for custom members fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, no. But there are two add-ons you should look at that will both give you the flexibility you need - both are from reputable developers.

- [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit)
- [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor)

Comment: Awesome thanks. I am already using a member software unfortunately but I think I will definitely give Zoo Visitor a try next time as it does have the feature I asked for

Comment: Actually we have refunded the module we brought and ended up buying Zoo Visitor which has done the job. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

For those comparing the various solutions, Focus Lab wrote a great blog post comparing the main member field type add-ons: http://focuslabllc.com/blog/member-profile-add-ons-in-expressionengine

What's missing in Derek's suggestion above is SafeCracker Registration. Never used it myself but Justin aka ObjectiveHTML is also a cool/good/reputable dude.

That being said, for the TL;DR folks, Focus Lab thinks Zoo Visitor was the best solution.